# Barcode scanners (Netum Scan) in python

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, pyserial

I'm writing code which takes input from several barcode scanners, and I want a way to differentiate between each scanner. I'm on windows 10, and my python version is 3.11.1. And as the title suggests, I'm using scanners from a company called Netum.

I've tried using them as HID devices, but this seems incredibly slow and impractical. If the computer sees them each as keyboards, I have to validate each individual keystroke, rather than entire barcodes. So I've abandoned this approach under that assumption.

I discovered these scanners have what's called "USB COM Port Emulation," and that seems promising. It almost never works, but when it does, it just shoves an entire barcode into my code as a string. The problem is that, most of the time, when it's in this mode, it disconnects the USB dongle the instant I scan anything. But it makes a reference to "needing drivers" for this mode. I checked the device manager, which tells me all my drivers are totally up-to-date. **This is really the crux of the problem**, as my code works if this mode works reliably.

Also, I'm using PySerial to decode the inputs from the scanners. I dunno if that matters, but I figured I'd mention it. The following is the code I'm using to talk to these janky scanners, and it only works when the scanners *don't* disconnect from my PC for seemingly no reason.

```
import serial

scanner = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=1, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
string = scanner.read()
print(string.decode())
scanner.close()
```

If anyone has any advice, insights, or even just general directions to point me in, it would be appreciated. I'm at the point where I don't even know how to begin solving this.

Comment: Have you installed any Virtual Com Port (VCP) drivers such as from FTDI?
https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/
They do a executable for easy install - this may help with your stability issues

Answer (score 0):

Comment to answer

Have you installed any Virtual Com Port (VCP) drivers such as from FTDI? ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers They do a executable for easy install - this may help with your stability issues